# Creating a secure CRUD class with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I created a class to handle CRUD more easily and got a problem.
My current class runs a crud in this syntax:

```
$crud = Core::Db()->builder();
$userData =$crud
                ->select("city,adress")
                ->from('users')
                ->where('name')
                ->like(':name')
                ->read(array(':name','%stefan'));
```

When you call crud method, automatically creates and inserts sql sentence to private variable $this->sql. write() prepare data and binds prepared statements(if exists).

Last example generates the following SQL:

$this-sql = "SELECT `city`,`address` FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE :name";

Everything works perfect. Binds :name and adds'%stefan'. All ok.

this is my problem. if i add :

```
$userData =$crud
                ->select("city,adress")
                ->from('users')
                ->where('name')
                ->like('%stefan')
                ->read();
```

returns :

```
//bad syntax
$this->sql = "SELECT `city`,`address` FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE %stefan";
```

If I add quotes to data, the second example will work fine, but the first will fail:

```
// First example, bad sintax
$this-sql = "SELECT `city`,`address` FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ':name'"; 

// Second example, good
$this-sql = "SELECT `city`,`address` FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%stefan' ";
```

I had thought of a solution ... Add quotes in like() method call and stripes it if the name is equal than a name of binded parameter binded in write():

```
private function write(array $input_parameters=array(),$style=NULL)
{
  // clean possible errors in holders
  foreach($input_parameters as $key => $value):
      if(strpos($this->sql,"'".$key."'") !== FALSE)
      $this->sql = str_replace("'".$key."'",$key,$this->sql);
      if(strpos($this->sql,'"'.$key.'"') !== FALSE)
          $this->sql = str_replace('"'.$key.'"',$key,$this->sql);
  endforeach;

  // .... code ....//
}
```

This solutions works fine in this case, but if you have something like this:

```
$userData =$crud
                ->select("id")
                ->from('blog')
                ->where('content')
                ->like(':word')
                ->_or('something')
                ->like(':word')
                ->read(array(':word','something'));
```

returns:

```
$this->sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `blog` WHERE `name` LIKE :word or `something` LIKE :word ";
```

This isn't a real life example, but its only for shows why i think its a bad solution, can become a security risk.

I cant find a way to binds data without secure problems, or damaged sql, i miss something here.

Can you think of anything else? I forgotten something? I'm paranoid? Now my head hurts so much, i cant think like a human.

Your help will be welcome, thanks

Comment: "cant think like a human." LOL =)) :))

Comment: I lost my sanity at this point